# Correct R formula syntax for lm (or manyglm) for a hierachial experimental design

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, error, lm, nested-data

I have an experimental data set where there are a 16 fish in 4 tanks (64 fish). There are two treatments - Heated and Control and four tanks. Heated was done in tank 1 and 2 whilst Control in Tank 3 and 4. At 4 different time points throughout the experiment (day 1,2,3 & 4), four fish were sampled and microbiomes analysed at four positions along the gut. Therefore I have 256 samples.

My question is: what is the correct formula syntax to input into the `manyglm` function (`package::mvabund`) to represent this sampling design?

Is it:

```
~ Treatment * Time + (1/Tank/Individual/GutLocation)
```

This is what the hierarchical structure of the experiment looks like.

```
Individual <- as.factor(rep(1:64, each=4))
GutLocation <- as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4), times=64))
Tank <- as.factor(rep(rep(1:4, each=16), time=4))
Treatment <- as.factor(rep(rep(1:2, each=32),times=4))
Time <-as.factor(rep(1:4, each=64))
x <- data.frame(cbind(Individual, GutLocation, Tank, Treatment, Time))
```

The sampling was destructive, so each fish 'individual' is a different fish that was sampled at four locations along the gut. The response data is a typical multivariate community matrix, hence why I am using glm's fitted to a negative binomial distribution.

I am really interested in how treatment effected the microbiomes (response matrix) while accounting for 'tank' effects. Pooling the 4 sub-samples from each individual (GutLocation) may be necessary and that is ok. The study is also longitudinal. There should be no difference between the treatments at T1, but I am expecting differences at time 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Where the fish identifiable, so the same four fish were sampled each time (and ID recorded), or not?

Comment: The formula you need will not only depend on the sampling design, but also the model you actually want to estimate, or hypothesis to tests. Can you elaborate? For instannce, for a growth curve model you will need to change the formula.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for your comment. No they are different fish. The sampling was destructive. I want to know the effect of the treatment while accounting for any 'tank effect' variation. I will add some code to represent the structure of the data.

I should add, the response data is multivariate, hence why I am using the mvabund R package and fitting negative binomial distributions.

Comment: Can you please add this new information as an exit to the Q, that way more people will see it. So this means you cannot estimate grotwh curves fir individual fish

Comment: No. I am not interested in growth curves. Rather how the microbiomes (the response matrix) differed between the two treatments. I really just need to know how to to correctly write the formula for input into the manyglm function to ensure I am capturing the different levels of replication.

Comment: Sampling is destructive means the fish are killed. So after 5he fourth day the tanks are empty. So you can simplify your formula, leave out the `Individual` term, with only one obs per fish that is unnecessary. Otherwise it looks ok. Will try to write an answer tomorrow, here now is bedtime!

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen I have added another sentence explaining the longitudinal nature of the study.